# Update keyword list for streaming API on-the-fly using HBC

Tags: twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

I'm working on a project accessing Twitter's Streaming API with [HBC](https://github.com/twitter/hbc).

I'm storing keywords for Twitters Streaming API (filter) in a file and now I'm looking for a way to close and reconnect to Twitter each time the file changes.

I googled with no useful result.

Any idea how I could manage this task?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this** Twitter doesn't like reconnects in stream API, they will ban your  application.
If you have to often change filter parameters better use Rest Api [search tweets endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

Comment: I need a stream of tweets.

Comment: HBC already implement the right policy for reconnection, so the problem is not what twitter likes or not likes.
We want to reconnect to the filtered stream using different "track keywords" without destroy and recreate the HBC client.